# using ice:selectOneMenu with f:ajax

Tags: jsf-2, liferay, portlet, icefaces

I developed portlet based on Icefaces and portletfaces. I used partialsubmit for ajax, but when I saw some post they said it should use out-of-the-box JSF 2 ajax support to avoid validation firing I tried to use f:ajax but doesn't work.

I also tried to use it out of the portlet environment doesn't work, I change the ice:selectOneMenu to h:selectOneMenu then got DOM exception.

the version of Icefaces is 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem through using old mechanism for JSF1 with immediate attribute and in the end of the change listener method I add this

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
```

and the validation not firing.